# Auto expire/delete messages from RabbitMQ queue after a certein time

Tags: rabbitmq

How can I delete each non processed messages from my queue automatically after 60 seconds?

Answer (score -1):

Use the option `x-message-ttl` in **queue properties**(not message properties).
set a value of milliseconds to auto expire messages

`x-message-ttl: 60000` means expire and remove each message after 60 seconds